# Linear Regression with measurement error

Tags: regression, linear, measurement-error

I'm searching for the analytical expression for the slope and its associated error in a simple regression problem. However, the independent variables $x_i$ have been obtained with a known measurement error of $\sigma_i$ .

Here I do not mean the inherent variability of the data, but the error in measuring it. For example take three points (x,y): (1,1),(2,2),(3,3). Calculate the slope and its associated error than that error would be equal to zero since the points correspond to a perfect line. However, if each point would have its associated measurement error, intuitively, there would still be an error on the estimation of the slope.

This question might be a duplicate of [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/165046/systematic-measurement-error-on-a-linear-regression)

Comment: You refer to "the dependent variables $x_i$" - is that what you intended to say or perhaps did you actually mean _independent_ there?

Comment: Yes, this has been changed.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you clarified that you have errors (with known variance) in your independent variables that you want to account for, I think what you're looking for is a [Deming Regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deming_regression) (for a simple linear regression) or [Total Least Squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_least_squares) (for multiple linear regression). Both model the degree of error in your independent variables (in addition to the error in your dependent variables), with the former being a special case of the latter.